# Android Studio - ¿Cómo lanzar un "gif" entre 2 activitys?

Tags: android, activity, gif

Cuando digo gif, me refiero a cualquier tipo de animación corta.

Tengo 2 Activitys, la primera hace una pregunta y calcula el resultado, la segunda muestra unos puntos.

Pues lo que me gustaría hacer es que una vez contesten en la primera actividad, antes de lanzar la segunda quiero que aparezca un gif durante 2 segundos. Y luego cargue la segunda actividad. ¿Es posible?

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view) {

                if (bt1.getText().equals("" + res2)) {
                    bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_true); aciertos++;
    //Aqui quiero mostrar un gif
                } else {
                    bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_false); fallos++;
    //Aqui quiero mostrar otro gif
                }
                siguienteActividad();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente inserte este código , Además, coloque su gif dentro de la carpeta `/assets` (si no tiene la carpeta de `/assets`, cree una debajo `src/main`)

```
WebView wView = new WebView(this);
wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/piggy.gif");
setContentView(view);
```

Para esperar 3 segundos y poder hacer el `intent` utiliza:

```
int DURACION_SPLASH = 3000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                // Cuando pasen los 3 segundos, pasamos a la segunda actividad 
                Intent intent = new Intent(act1, act2);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            };
        }, DURACION_SPLASH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Además de la respuesta de @Bruno Sosa Fast Tag, puede usar biblioteca [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para cargar cualquier `imagen` o `GIF` en Android.

```
Glide.with(TU_CONTEXTO)
.load(TU_GIF)
.into(TU_IMAGEN_VIEW);
```

Use Glide para cargar imágenes normales, imágenes del servidor etc...

> Glide es un marco de carga de imágenes y administración de medios de código abierto rápido y eficiente para Android que integra la decodificación de medios, la memoria y el almacenamiento en caché de discos y la agrupación de recursos en una interfaz simple

Answer (score 1):

**En realidad no se "lanza un .gif", lo que deseas es cargar un .gif animado y posteriormente realizar un intent para abrir una nueva Activity.**

Ademas de usar un `WebView` como comenta [Bruno Sosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159566/95), también puedes usar un `ImageView`

Usando [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para carga un .gif animado dentro de un `ImageView`.

```
    String urlGif = "https://dominio.com/myanimation.gif";
    //add Glide implementation into the build.gradle file.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlGif);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

[image]

Después de mostrar el .gif animado puedes iniciar la siguiente Activity

```
new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

                //Muestra siguiente Activity.
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SiguienteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);



        }
    }, 2000); //2000 millisegundos = 2 segundos, para cargar la siguiente Activity.
```

---

Para mostrar un .gif animado no únicamente desde los recursos si no cargando desde un url de internet, estas son dos opciones:

[Como cargar un gif animado en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159604/como-cargar-un-gif-animado-en-android/159605#159605)