# Como cargar un gif animado en Android

Tags: android, webview, gif

Existen librerías para realizar la carga de gifs animados dentro de una aplicación, pero ¿cual sería la forma adecuada de cargar gifs animados sin usar libraries de terceros o vistas personalizadas?

[GifImageView](http://www.mavengang.com/2016/05/02/gif-animation-android/)

[GifView](http://www.geeks.gallery/how-to-display-the-animated-gif-image-in-android/)

[GifMovieView](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/)

Habíar realizado carga de .gif usando `WebView` de esta forma:

```
   WebView webView =  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myanimation.gif");
```

**Pero además se desea que el .gif se encuentre en una url y no dentro de los recursos del proyecto.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen dos opciones para cargar gifs animados en una aplicación Android. mediante estos métodos se pueden cargar gifs animado desde una url.

**1) Usando [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para cargar el gif animado dentro de un `ImageView`.**

```
    String urlGif = "https://domain.com/myanimatedgif.gif";
    //Agregar implementacion Glide dentro de archivo build.gradle.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlGif);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

**2) Usando un html para cargar el gif animado dentro de un `WebView`**.

Crea un html que contenga la ruta hacia el archivo .gif:

```
<html style="margin: 0;">
<body style="margin: 0;">
<img src="https://..../myimage.gif" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
</body>
</html>
```

almacena este archivo .html dentro del directorio `/assets`:

[image]

Ahora carga el html dentro de un `WebView` en tu aplicación:

```
    WebView webView =  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/webpage_gif.html");
```

---

Aquí existe un [**ejemplo completo que muestra ambas opciones**](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-animated-Gifs).

[image]

Comment: Excelente aporte @Jorge !!! Un saludo!! (y)

Comment: Muchas gracias @GustavoMora saludos!

Answer (score 2):

En tú archivo de `gradle` en la parte de `dependencies` agrega:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

Y en la parte de java donde este leyendo la imagen coloca

```
if(isGif(dirImagen)){
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asGif().load(dirImagen).into(imga);
}
else{
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(dirImagen).into(imga);
}

private boolean isGif(String imagen) {
    String extension = "";
    int i = imagen.lastIndexOf('.');
    int p = Math.max(imagen.lastIndexOf('/'), imagen.lastIndexOf('\\'));
    if (i > p) {
        extension = imagen.substring(i+1);
    }
    return extension.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("gif");
}
```

Se pregunta si es gif para que mejore la carga, al no leer el gif como gif estas demoran en mostrarse en la pantalla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu contribución, sabes, desconocía el método asGif(), veo que internamente optimiza la carga para un gif animado, saludos!